# MySql / Odbc connection problem

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

I'm accessing a MySql database via ODBC. It normally works fine, but if the database is stopped and restarted I have to restart my application in order to reconnect to the database.

The code for accessing the database is like this:

```
        OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectString);
        OdbcCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "select * from cds";
        OdbcDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        connection.Open();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        connection.Close();
```

After a restart of the database, I get a 'MySql server has gone away' exception in dataAdapter.Fill method. Is 
there any way I can reconnect to the database when I detect that the connection has broken?

I use VS2008 and MySql 5.1.30.

Comment: I would say restarting MySQL is not really a normal operation, plus you can handle the exception and reconnect no ?

Comment: that "MySQL Server has gone away", pisses me to no end.  I switched to PostgreSQL, no problem such as that, glad i switched. Plus i have a query that is 45 seconds before in MySQL, when ported to Postgresql became 6 seconds.  I wish I've discovered the solution to that intermittent MySQL problem so I can provide an answer here.  What I can do now is just upvote whoever has an idea how to prevent that problem in MySQL

Comment: When I try to handle the exception, I still get a new exception on the call to dataAdapter.Fill() method.

Answer (score 0):

This "restart the application in order to reconnect to the database" is simply a bad design decision. The initialization of the database connection should not be put in the startup code, instead put it in a separate procedure, and in case one of your methods got the exception "MySql server has gone away" simply call this procedure in order to re-initialize the connection to the DB.

Comment: I agree that restarting the application to reconnect is bad, that's why I'm looking for a better way. I open and close the connection every time I access the database, but this is apparently not enough to reconnect. Does anyone know of any other way to close/reopen a database?